# Erro Conexao JDBC Mysql no Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

Estou tentando conectar o banco mysql a partir de minha aplicação JAVA.
Porém recebo esta mensagem:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 31

```
28:     String action="";
29:     
30:         String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3606/crudjsp;create=true";
31:         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
32:         
33:         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root"," ");
34:         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

**Imagem do ambiente:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca a stacktrace inteira na pergunta

Comment: Você adicionou o driver do mysql no classpath?

Comment: Não! Apenas no projeto. Como mostrado na imagem.

Comment: Dá uma olhada se essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118069/cannot-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-tomcat-8-eclipse/36118190#36118190) te ajuda.

Comment: Recebi  essa mensagem: HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 33
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 33
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 33

30:   String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/crudjsp";
31:   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
32: 
33:   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root"," ");

Comment: Se não adicionar no classpath não vai reconhecer o driver. Clica no jar com o direito do mouse e selecione `add to build classpath`

Comment: Estou usando o eclipse NEON. Não tem esse opcão!

Comment: Eu tb utilizo eclipse neon e tem essa opção sim. Passa o mouse na opcao `build path` que ela aparece no submenu.

Comment: Porém, consegui inserir no Classpath

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema inserindo o .jar do mysql no classpath e  colocando a porta 3306 no codigo.